# Error codes for watchdog daemon

Tags: linux, watchdog

Here's a line from a linux syslog:

```
watchdog[2423]: shutting down the system because of error 101
```

However, after searching online and in `man watchdog`, I cannot find any discussion or explanation of the error codes.  Is there any such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, per the same manual page:

```
TEST BINARY
       If the return code of the check binary is not zero watchdog will assume
       an error and reboot the system. A positive exit code is interpreted as
       a system error code (see errno.h for details).
```

so in this particular case (`error 101`), according to `errno.h`:

```
ENETUNREACH 101 /* Network is unreachable */
```

Comment: The most recent watchdog code includes text versions of the error codes (as well as other bug-fixes and improvements): https://sourceforge.net/p/watchdog/code/ci/master/tree/ You should be able to build it for your application.

Comment: Note file name has changed. See https://sourceforge.net/p/watchdog/code/ci/master/tree/include/watch_err.h